# Need some assistance around Applovin's MAX & Ironsource's LevelPlay for In-App bidding

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mobile-ad-mediation, applovin, ironsource

I'd like some guidance to get started, in terms of the documentation. I can't find an implementation guide as such. Been beating around the bush for couple of days in finding the best out of these 2. What would really help here is some kinda implementation documentation/videos for Unity which would help in getting the ball rolling. Can't really find any kinda demo videos/code samples as such around the web.

Comment: Good to know you already knew policies before. I like you to update your questions with some of your research code, links or any articles which you tried before. This question doesn't contains any of these. It's just plain question only, without showing any effort to solve the problem.

Comment: @MathiArasan : Like i said, i'm trying to get started. Both Applovin & IronSource talks about their capacity to handle in-app bidding using their SDKs. But they do not share an implementation guide as such(Like Admob gives in their developer site). Applovin is still reviewing my play store account(Been around 20 days) & IronSource doesn't give a documentation as such to get started. I don't want any help in terms of the technicality here. Just looking for documentation for both & I'll get going from there. So it would be great if you can share links if you have any... like any PDFs etc

Comment: You may contact/submit a request to Ironsrc. You may come across with this but if not [check this link for bidding](https://developers.ironsrc.com/ironsource-mobile/general/bidding-api-v2/#step-1)